# How do I get random floats in a numpy array between 0 and 0.20?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to get a 6 x 6 array that will contain floats between 0 and 0.20.

I looked over the Sci Py documentation, and it looks like I can achieve this in a uniform distribution, but its only between 0 and 1 (from my understanding) and it seems like most of the other "random" functions either have only integer functions, or its only between 0 and 1.

I may have missed something when I was reading, but I'm just wondering if anyone knows a numpy function that would satisfy random floats between 0 and 0.20 (or any other custom float that's not just 1) that is NOT **normal** distribution.

Again, I might have just missed something so this might be the simplest answer (which I'm sure it will be).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "purely random". Those numbers come from _some_ distribution.

Comment: @coldspeed I think OP means uniform distribution

Comment: @timgeb The question is unclear (deja vu?!) because they say "that is NOT uniform distribution"...  not sure what they want honestly :(

Comment: @coIdspeed I'm convinced that it's unclear. Hey, maybe we could randomize the distribution for each number? :D

Comment: My apologies, for some reason I put uniform and I meant normal distribution

Comment: it's common to transform values from RNGs.  in your case, you could have just multiplied the U(0,1) generator by 0.2 to get your required U(0,0.2) distribution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`np.random.uniform` is what you're looking for:

```
numpy.random.uniform(0, 0.2, size=(6,6))
```

(example) result:

```
array([[0.14096821, 0.10244225, 0.07058027, 0.10072557, 0.13587906,
        0.1005836 ],
       [0.03105747, 0.18675986, 0.11239678, 0.09210644, 0.17902008,
        0.01757712],
       [0.01838364, 0.04447954, 0.14783771, 0.15361297, 0.0621943 ,
        0.17602198],
       [0.10187598, 0.18661528, 0.03667612, 0.00167146, 0.06079677,
        0.12671214],
       [0.05329904, 0.07689386, 0.1882259 , 0.04242195, 0.0059735 ,
        0.04418237],
       [0.05279836, 0.0861716 , 0.04787015, 0.09390129, 0.05019911,
        0.13027479]])
```